# How to Map SetState functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mapping, material-ui

How can I map setState functions?

Here's my setState function example:

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
```

Here is my mapping technique:

```
  {[{ label: "First Name", state: 'firstName' , function: 'setFirstName'},
                  { label: "Last Name", state: 'lastName' },
                  { label: "Email", state: 'email' },
                  { label: "Password", state: 'password' },
                  { label: "Phone", state: 'phone' }].map((item, index) => (
                    <div>
                      <TextField
                        id="outlined-basic"
                        key={index}
                        label={item.label}
                        variant="outlined"
                        onChange= {e => setFirstName(e.target.value)}          
                      />
                      <br></br><br></br>
                    </div>
                  )
  )}
```

This works but I want to change the onChange in such a way that instead of setFirstName, I can pass in the function and map all of them (eg firstName, lastName etc).  How could I fix this?

Comment: Could you elaborate it more? do you want all records firstName and last name in state or something else?

Comment: Yo'r question is not clear, please provide minimal working example

Comment: Remove the quotes around `setFirstName` and add the `function` attribute to all the objects. Then call the function in onChange `e => item.function(e.target.value)`?

Comment: @adiga yup that worked! Could you please take a look at my edited/added qs? I came up with another problem

Comment: @Ashish Could you please take a look at the added/edited qss

Comment: Please post a new question instead of editing to ask another question: [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the quotes for `state` and `function` and use `function` inside `onChange`.

```
    [
      { label: 'first name', state: firstName, function: setFirstName },
      { label: 'last name', state: lastName, function: setLastName },
    ].map((item, index) => (
      <TextField
        key={index}
        label={item.label}
        onChange={e => item.function(e.target.value)} // use state function       
      />
    ))
```

Comment: This works! Just one more thing, after my textfield, I want to print the value to check it. 
If I use ```<Typography>{item.state}</Typography>```, I get 'firstName'/'lastName' printed. However, I want
to print the values stored in those variables. If I say item.state.value, I get an error.

Comment: @x89, remove the quotes for the state variables as shown given that `firstName` and `lastName` store string values and not objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an object to track a form's state but here's how I'd map different set state actions.

```js
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');

const textFields = [
  {
    label: 'First name',
    onChange: handleChange(setFirstName),
    value: firstName
  },
  {
    label: 'Last name',
    onChange: handleChange(setLastName),
    value: lastName
  }
];

const handleChange = setStateAction => ({ target }) => {
  setStateAction(target.value);
}

return textFields.map((props, index) => (
  <TextField key={index} {...props} />
));
```

Comment: Great idea. Could you please take a look at my edited/added qs? I came up with another problem

Comment: `How could I modify the textfields properties in this map? For example, if I write` You can save textFields array in a state and update the current field. What do you mean both onChanges? `I get an error. Also, how can I use both the onChanges now?`